# fatal error: call to undefined method database::prepare

Tags: php, apache

I'm using php7 and msaccess database, my problem is sometimes the message "fatal error: call to undefined method database::prepare" popup in case of user trying to perform login to my website.
after I perform restart to web server (apache 2.4) the login process works again and the message gone but the message keep popup from time to time and it requires web server restart again.
is there anyway to avoid this message from popup again rather than restarting web server please advice...

First off **Database** Class:

```
class database extends PDO
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        try
        {
            parent::__construct("odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};Dbq=".dbPath.";Uid=; Pwd=".PWD.";charset=utf8");
        }
        catch(Exception $msg)
        {
            echo $msg->getMessage();
        }

    } 
}
```

Next: **Model** Class:

```
class model
{
    public $db;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->db=new database();
    }

}
```

Last: **login_model** class:

```
class login_model extends model{
public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }
 public  function run(){

      $sth=$this->db->prepare("select count(*) from BasicInfo where code=:code and Password=:password");
       $sth->execute(array(":code"=>$_POST["code"],":password"=>$_POST["password"]));
       $count=$sth->fetch();
        Session::Init();
if($count[0]>0)
                { 


                    Session::Set("login","ok");
                    Session::Set("code",$_POST["code"]);
                    echo "ok";

                }
                 else
                {


                    header( 'location: '. url .'errorlogin/index');

                } 
}
```

Comment: So under some conditions, that object isn't defined. You'll need to show some code for any specific help. Restarting the server shouldn't affect this at all.

Comment: that what happens with me after restart web server the code works again i'm using database class which inherits pdo class, anyway i'm posting the code

Comment: Human error... .

Comment: that what happens with me after restart web server the code works again i'm using database class which inherits pdo class, anyway i'm posting the code @Qirel

Comment: So, @IS_ELKADY - you copied your first comment, tagged me and didn't post the code still? Can't help you any more than before. No code, I'm afraid.

Comment: code has been posted @Qirel

Comment: Please help @gordon linoff